# Tomcat server is running but i can't access it anymore

Tags: tomcat

I installed a tomcat server on my remote debian10 server. It used to be functional but since I tried to add SSL key configuration to /opt/tomcat/server.xml, I can't reach http://{domain-name}:8080. I tried to revert my changes but nothing changed.

I tried `sudo systemctl status tomcat` to verify that tomcat was running and it was.
I checked catalina logs and netstat.
There are no logs in catalina except for tomcat restart.
Netstat command showed that java is listening to the port 8080.

Does someone have any idea of what it could be ?

Comment: Is there anything in catalina,log or catalina.out?

Comment: I checked but there are only lines concerning the restart of tomcat.

Comment: I also checked netstat and java is listening to the port 8080. Apache is listening to the port 80 and i can establish the connexion.